# Align center consistantly accross single page

Tags: html, css, plotly-dash

I have a `dash` application, and I wanted to give two `datatable` a `header`. So I did this:

```
html.Div(
    html.H2(
                'Title-1',
                style={'color': 'orange', 'text-align': 'center'},     
        )
    ),
    html.Div(
        id = 'datatable-opps1',
        className = 'datatable-opps1'
    ),
    html.Div(
        html.H2(
                'Title-1',
                style={'color': 'orange', 'text-align': 'center'},     
        )
    ),
    html.Div(
        id = 'datatable-opps2',
        className = 'datatable-opps2'
    ),
```

Unfortunately even though they are both `align center`, the header for the top table displays in one place "center" different than the header for the header for the second table.

Is there a way to say, I want a `header` to be an absolute number of `points` from the left? Or maybe even better, have the `table` display its own title?

Comment: why not just use `margin-left`?

Comment: It works. I am worried that since I don't know what the size of the person's page is, that I will go to far...

Comment: Or as the page gets resized, things won't look right

Comment: make sure your divs are in the same width